# error binding 'matMenuTriggerFor' to button in simple component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add a menu material to a simple project see:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11cjdg?file=src/app/header/header.component.ts

But I keep getting Can't bind to 'matMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

I have tryed to follow https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-icons-example.ts and https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material?file=src%2Fangular-material%2Fangular-material.module.ts but this error will not go away. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import you angular material modules in app.module, not in the component
So your app.module should look like this.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,  MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,    MatCardModule,    MatToolbarModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, HeaderComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and you header component like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: I updated the stackblitz and it still gives the same error

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ftp-demo-vlk8aj?file=src/app/header/header.component.html

Comment: did you try to run npm install on the root of your project?, i can't i canot run command on stackblitz

Comment: I also made stackblitz work by deleting all dependencies and adding back manually. not very graceful but it worked there too